# .htaccess config to make content of dot-folder visible from web browser?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, diem-cms

I'm currently working with Diem CMS / Symfony powered website. After migrating to new host, some images on site are not visible. Firebug shouts: "403" when trying to access these images. Unfortunately images are stored in /uploads/some_folder/**.thumb**/image_name.jpg

- I've tried to change permissions - no luck
- I've tried to create symlinks for **.thumbs** (named **thumbs**) and
  rewrite in .htaccess - no luck
- I've tried .htaccess tricks like Options Indexes, allow from all etc. - no luck

I've ended with copying content of **.thumbs** folders to **thumbs**, and rewrite in .htaccess - it is working but obviously I'm not satisfied with this solution.

Comment: I don't know if what you're asking is possible but I would suggest that trying to make hidden files, (which is what the dot does), viewable through the web server is not a good idea from a security perspective. I think renaming the folder to remove the dot is best.

Comment: Yeah, it would be best idea, but... these images are managed by some of Diem's plugin. I've found occurences of **.thumbs** folders in code only in method responsible for deleting them. Methods that are responsible for creating, viewing and editing are using some constants (propably taken from database and I have no access there (lol)). I can't simply rename folder because it will mess everything. Ealier (on previous web host) everything, including serving images from dot-folders was working fine.